# How to remove a event listener in the context of dragging a React component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-functional-component

The `mousemove` does not appear to be properly removed from `document` when releasing the mouse.

https://codesandbox.io/s/dragondrop-dqs46

Comment: I suspect that `useCallback` yields an instance of my actual function, and that it's a different instance everytime the effect is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than manually adding and removing *when* relevant, write a custom hook `useEvent` that will store handlers from one render to another:

#### `useEvent.js`

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function(event, handler, element=window) {

  const savedHandler = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedHandler.current = handler;
  }, [handler]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventListener = event => savedHandler.current(event);
    element.addEventListener(event, eventListener);
    return () => element.removeEventListener(event, eventListener);
  }, [event, element]);
}
```

#### `components/Dragon.js`

```js
useEvent("mousemove", onDrag);
useEvent("mouseup", onDragEnd);
```

Working pen: https://codesandbox.io/s/dragondrop-ceocx